# Ionic 3 API Authorization

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I don't understand why the following code works:

```html
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/getEvts', {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token),
      }).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
```

while this code doesn't work :

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/getEvts', options).subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Can anyone explain please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work cause of get method parameters :

```
get(url: string, options: {
  headers?: HttpHeaders | {
    [header: string]: string | string[];
  };
  observe?: 'body';
  params?: HttpParams | {
    [param: string]: string | string[];
  };
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  responseType: 'arraybuffer';
  withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>
```

As you can see a `RequestOptions` object is not a valid argument.

Answer (score 0):

You use RequestOptions when instantiating a Request object. I don't even know why you are using there. Like another user said the RequestOptions isn't a parameter in the http.get method. The parameters is an object with the following properties:

`{
headers,
observe,
params,
reportProgress,
responseType,.
withCredentials
}`

Where only ResponseType is a valid value.